# Stieltjes Transform is injective?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, integral-transforms

Let $\mu$ a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, we define the Stieltjes transform  by :
$$
S[\mu](\lambda)=\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{d\mu(t)}{t-\lambda}
$$
For all $\lambda\in\Omega:=\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$.

For which conditions $S$ will be injective, from the set of probability measure to the set of holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ ?